# Как обрабатывать кириллицу на си в линукс?

Tags: c

Мне нужно обработать файл на русском языке на языке си, если можно, то как, wchar_t?

Comment: *wchar_t* -- специальный 16-битовый тип, охватывающий 0 страницу Unicode. Ура, кириллица как раз туда входит! Но помимо этого знания нужно понимать в какой кодировке изначально файл создан. Windows оперирует UTF-16, в Linux -- чаще всего UTF-8. Обратите внимание, что UTF8 -- многобайтовая кодировка: символ может быть представлен одним, двумя, и так далее до 6 байт. Соответственно существует некоторое количество API для конвертации между ними. Надо понимать, что *wchar_t* - это тоже своего рода кодировка.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно непонятно, что означает:

1. файл на русском языке
2. на языке си

Если Вы имеете в виду обработку плоских текстовых файлов в кодировке UTF-8, в системе, в которой локаль настроена на использование UTF-8, то никаких проблем не возникает. Вот пример простейшей программы, которая выполняет стандартную обработку:

1. Открывает файл
2. Читает из него текст
3. Что-то делает с этим текстом
4. Выводит результат.

Проверка работы с UTF-8 на С:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buf[2048];
    char *cp;
    FILE *in_stream;
    int len;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Недопустивый список параметров! Используйте:\n");
        printf ("%s <Файл для обработки>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    in_stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (in_stream == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка при открытии файла '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        abort();
    }


    cp = fgets(buf, 2048, in_stream);
    while (cp != NULL) {
        len = fputs(buf, stdout);
        cp = fgets(buf, 2048, in_stream);
    }

    fclose(in_stream);

}
```

Никаких проблем не возникло. Другое дело, что обрабатывая текст в кодировки UTF-8, необходимо помнить о том, что длина строки в символах и количество байт в этой строке - совсем не одно и тоже!

Comment: Не знаю почему, но так и не смог правильно отформатировать пример кода...

Comment: а как мне работать с кириллицей посимвольно. В ascii я знаю как работать, там по индексу взял символ и делай с ним что хочешь

Comment: **как мне работать с кириллицей посимвольно**  - Вопрос, конечно, интересный... :-) В самом простом случае - воспользоваться функцией *iconv()*  для того, что бы перевести utf-8 в любую однобайтовую кодировку, выполнить обработку, а затем - обратный перевод.  Более подробно можете посмотреть тут:

https://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/257895/

Comment: Есть ещё вариант - сделать всю обработку текста на Python-3 и подключить этот модуль к программе на С. В третьем питоне всё сделано в рамках языка.

Comment: Для начала определиться с желаемыми интерфейсами, т.е. понять, как вы хотите работать со строками и зачем. Хотите символы по индексу получать? Конвертим кириллицу (если это точно кириллица) в свою временную кодировку и работаем с байтиками. Если это не только кириллица, но и что-то китайское может быть - конвертим в uint32_t (utf32) и у нас полная свобода снова. Хотим работать именно со строками - у нас и так все хорошо, только символы разрывать нельзя. В общем, подумайте над задачей и решите именно ее.

Answer (score 0):

"на русском языке", понятие растяжимое. В пограммировании есть понятие "кодировка". Для windows-1251, koi-8 и cp866 использовать char. Если utf-8 или utf-16 - wchar_t.

Comment: Я знаю, что есть кодировка, но как ее в си применить, чтобы вместо русских символов не было кракозябр?

Comment: Разве для UTF-8 не логичнее `char`? Это же кодировка с различным количеством байт.

Comment: систему в смысле  винда или линух? Так проще будет

Comment: не логичнее. Если файл с однобайтовой, русской, тогда что utf что угодно. Все равно кракозябры будут

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63848/discussion-on-answer-by-maint-------).

Comment: @Ainar-G вообще-то и UTF-16 с разным количеством байт.

Answer (score -1):

Есть небольшая библиотека: [UTF8Strings](http://grigory.info/UTF8Strings.About.html), которая позволяет сождавать и работать с UTF-8 строками

Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UTF8Strings/Exception.h"
#include "UTF8Strings/String.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  try {
    UTF8::String s("абWERвгд");
    cout << s.Length() << endl;
    cout << s[1] << " " << s[4] << endl;
    cout << s.Substring(1, 2) << endl;
  } catch (UTF8::Exception e) {
    std::cout << "Catched: " << e.GetErrorString();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

создание строки, содержащей русские и английские буквы

```
UTF8::String s("абWERвгд");
```

Получение правильной длинны строки в символах

```
сout << s.Length() << endl;
```

Получение символов по индексу в строке

```
cout << s[1] << " " << s[4] << endl;
```

Получение подстроки

```
cout << s.Substring(1, 2) << endl;
```

Comment: Как пользоваться этой библиотекой? Привидите пример.

Comment: Это не си . . .